# Nebular component can't present correctly

Tags: angular, nebular

I follow the step in official document to use nebular component. The Layout is fine, but when I use card component or other component.

[image: some bug happen]

This is my Html

```
<nb-card>
  <nb-menu [items]="items">
  </nb-menu>
</nb-card>
```

```
items: NbMenuItem[] = [{
    title: 'Profile',
    expanded: true,
    children: [{
        title: 'Change Password',
      },
      {
        title: 'Privacy Policy',
      },
      {
        title: 'Logout',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Shopping Bag',
  },
  {
    title: 'Orders',
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that styles of nebular is globally and that all themes are correctly defined.
I had a similar issue before, and it's because my styles.scss was incomplete.